Local autocomplete for a bash script
I really want to add autocomplete to my scripts for custom options, but all the advice I see online involves updating /etc/bash_completion.d or ~/.bashrc. The problem with this method for me is that this is a global solution (for the system in the case of updating /etc/... and for the user in the case of ~/.bashrc). A lot of times, I have many small scripts only applicable to the directory they're in. Thus, a "global" solution might break if I had distinct scripts with the same name in different directories (which I often do). Thus, I'd like a solution which scopes to the current directory, maybe adding some code to the script itself, or adding an "autocomplete file" alongside a script.
Here's an example of what I'd like:
~/working_directory$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "opt1" ]]; then
    echo "performing action 1"
fi
if [[ "$1" == "opt2" ]]; then
    echo "performing action 2"
fi
~/working_directory$ cat script.autocomplete.txt
opt1
opt2
~/working_directory$ ./script.sh op
Options from script.autocomplete.txt:
opt1
opt2
~/working_directory$ ./script.sh opt

The last 5 lines is what I'd like to see when the user enters tab after typing part of some option.
One more feature I'd like is that it works when the script doesn't have the execution bit set (e.g. bash -e script.sh) as sometimes I work in strange bash environments (like termux) where using chmod require arcane knowledge.
If no one responds, I think I have an idea for how to do this (there was a post I found to add general and customizable autocomplete) and I'll update this post with my findings.

Doesn't sound like a good idea.

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

You could use this to execute a script when you enter each directory, and it could load that directory's completions.

@Barmar ah, sorry, I meant to post this in Unix&Linux... Should I delete this? Or can a mod move it?

You can flag it and ask the mods to move it.

One hack I thought of for this is to just put the options as dummy files in the directory. In the example above, this would replace the script.autocomplete.txt. Here's the updated example:
~/working_directory$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "opt1" ]]; then
    echo "performing action 1"
fi
if [[ "$1" == "opt2" ]]; then
    echo "performing action 2"
fi
~/working_directory$ ls opt*
opt1
opt2
~/working_directory$ ./script.sh op
opt1
opt2
~/working_directory$ ./script.sh opt

One problem is if an option conflicts with a file. To solve this, you could put the options in a directory: ./options/opt{1,2} and check for those as options:
~/working_directory$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" == "options/opt1" ]]; then
    echo "performing action 1"
fi
if [[ "$1" == "options/opt2" ]]; then
    echo "performing action 2"
fi

This is still pretty hacky, but might be a fine solution since it is a hacky problem anyway.
